# How can I integrate OpenAI Whisper model into a Kotlin app?

Tags: android, kotlin, openai-api, openai-whisper

I require guidance on incorporating Whisper OpenAI into my Android application developed with Kotlin in Android Studio. Unfortunately, I haven't come across any relevant instructions or details regarding its installation and utilization in this particular environment. I would like to use Whisper for transcribing audio to text.

I am attempting to establish a connection between Whisper and my Android application developed using Kotlin.

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain what went wrong with it. Refer to [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Python code using Chaquopy in my app, and it has proven to be a satisfactory solution for me. But if you want still use kotlin code, you can use curl. Here it is: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests